What regex should I use to get inotifywait --include to trigger upon the creation of a file with a known fixed filename?
I want to use inotifywait to run code upon the creation of a file with a known fixed filename. This answer correctly explains that I cannot run inotifywait directly against a file that does not yet exist and that instead, I should run inotifywait against the parent directory, with an include argument that contains a suitable regex to match the specified filename. If I use the regular expression that that answer suggests, however, I find that other filenames match:
inotifywait -m -e close_write --format %f --include 'hello\.txt' .

# (Then, in another terminal...)
touch hello.txt   # Prints hello.txt - this is good.
touch ahello.txt  # Prints ahello.txt - this is bad.
touch hello.txta  # Prints hello.txta - this is bad.
touch ahello.txta # Prints ahello.txta - this is bad.

"That's easy to fix", I say to myself. "I'll just add in the usual metacharacters to mark the start and end of the string."
inotifywait -m -e close_write --format %f --include '^hello\.txt$' .

# (Then, in another terminal...)
touch ahello.txta  # Prints nothing - this is good.
touch ahello.txt   # Prints nothing - this is good.
touch hello.txta   # Prints nothing - this is good.
touch hello.txt    # Prints nothing - this is bad.

man inotifywait clearly states --include <pattern> will "process events only for the subset of files whose filenames match the specified POSIX regular expression, case sensitive." and I can see the filenames (as inotifywait sees them) printed in the first block of code above: when I typed in touch hello.txt, inotifywait printed hello.txt so I know that inotifywait thinks that the filename is hello.txt.
Why is my regular expression ^hello\.txt$ not matching the filename hello.txt? What should I be using instead?

Despite inotifywait --format %f printing hello.txt, that it NOT what it thinks is the filename. What it thinks is the filename is ./hello.txt. Hence the correct regex is ^\./hello\.txt$:
inotifywait -m -e close_write --format %f --include '^\./hello\.txt$' .

# (Then, in another terminal...)
touch hello.txt   # Prints hello.txt - this is good.
touch ahello.txt  # Prints nothing - this is good.
touch hello.txta  # Prints nothing - this is good.  
touch ahello.txta # Prints nothing - this is good.   

